# Testing a simple javascript button

Tags: javascript, events, button, submit

Hello gentlemen and ladies. I'm trying to test the button to see if it binds to event but it's not working. I have been at this for hours and couldn't find the answer.I'm looking for code that separates the HTML and javsScript. I'm new and I really appreciate your time. I can't get the alert to work when I click button.

```js
var formId;

 formId = document.GetElementById("button");
function run(){
  
 alert("Stack overflow"); 
  
}


formId.addEventListener("submit", run, false);
```

```html
  <div id ="content">
    <div id ="title">Special Offers</div>
    <div id="colors">Sign-up to receive personalized    offers!
    </div>
      
     <fieldset>
       <legend> Please enter your information</legend>
        <form action="#" method="post" />
         <input type="text"  />
            <label for ="button">add</label>
       </form>
                
      </fieldset>
    
    <!--**************Button******-->
    
    <button type="submit" id="button">submit</button>
    
 </div>
```

Comment: Change `GetElementById` to `getElementById`.

Comment: Buttons don't have a `submit` event, only forms have that event. You should bind to the `click` event.

Comment: `<form>` tags should go outside the `<fieldset>`, not inside it.

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem? Just wondering.

Answer (score 1):

Try ...

```
var formId = document.getElementById("button");

function run(){
  alert("Stack overflow"); 
}

formId.addEventListener("click", run, false);
```

Where I am using `.getElementById` (spelling) and the click event on the Listener.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/9duqfgL6/

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code:

```
<div id ="content">
    <div id ="title">Special Offers
    </div>
    <div id="colors">Sign-up to receive personalize offers!
    </div>         
    <button type="submit" id="button" onclick="run()">submit</button>
</div>
```

and your JS should be as follows:

```
function run(){
    alert("stack overflow");
}
```

Comment: Please don't invite him to use inline JS, it's unnecessary and does not help getting code organized.

Comment: Don't promote inline handlers if he's trying to learn the more modern style of `addEventListener`.

Comment: Agreed. HTML, CSS and JS should be separate.

Comment: nice guys, I'm learning myself here too, which is fantastic. You are all far more experienced than me so I would certainly not disagree either.

Interesting article here that I just read

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/javascript/working-with-inline-event-handlers.html#fbid=aAeIj8YXAh6

Answer (score 0):

Your `form` tag was self closing. It should be `getElementById`. Try the `click` event instead of the `submit` event.

Your `button` is outside the `form`. When you have your button inside it, you can add the `submit` event listener to your form.

```js
var formId = document.getElementById("button");
function run(){
  alert("Stack Overflow"); 
}
formId.addEventListener("click", run, false);
```

```html
<div id ="content">
  <div id ="title">Special Offers</div>
  <div id="colors">Sign-up to receive personalized offers!</div>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> Please enter your information</legend>
    <form action="#" method="post">
      <input type="text"/>
      <label for="button">add</label>
      <button type="submit" id="button">submit</button>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you need to put your `form` outside of the `fieldset` and include the `button` in the form if you want your button outside of the fieldset.

Comment: I want to thank you guys for taking time out of your busy schedule to help. I got the code working and I took time to understand everything you gentlemen mentioned.